# Using Torque with Cartodb

Tags: carto

Is torque supposed to be part of Cartodb visualizations by default?  It doesn't show up for me. All I get is simple, choropeth, category, bubble.

This post and video

(http://blog.cartodb.com/post/66687861735/torque-is-live-try-it-on-your-cartodb-maps-today)

make it seem like there's nothing to install or setup so I'm wondering why it's not working for me.

I'm just using a free account, but the website above says Cartodb has released it to all users so I don't think that should matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Torque currently only works with point data. The wizards give different options depending on if your data is point, line or polygon. So I'm guessing you're trying to visualize lines or polygons?

That capability should come in torque in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Having faced the same problem just a hint.
You can dump your geography to points and then animate the points with torque. E.g. in my case to convert Multilines into points:

```
SELECT (ST_DumpPoints(
ST_Segmentize(the_geom, 1))).geom as new_the_geom FROM ...
```

The second parameter in ST_Segmentize defines the maximal distance between 2 ponts in meters or in degrees.